# Why are my COM ports busy?

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, usb

I have a python program I am using to talk to a microcontroler. It opens the com ports like this:

```
def STM32_connect():  
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        if "STM32" in p.description:
            connection = serial.Serial(p.device, timeout = .01)
            return(connection)
    print("ERROR: No STM32 Device Found")
    sys.exit()

serial_connection = STM32_connect()
```

And then does a bunch of things, sending and receiving data until I close the program like this with a keyboard interput:

```
except:
    print("\n Program Interrupted...")
finally:
    print("\n Closing Serial Port\n")
    serial_connection.close()
```

This all works fine. My problem is when the python script is improperly killed by disconnecting the USB cable or powering off the board I can no longer connect to the micro on any COM port. I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/---/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "flextester.py", line 1, in <module>
        from flex_usb_class import *
      File "/home/---/Code/RobotFlexTester/flex_usb_class.py", line 30, in <module>
        serial_connection = STM32_connect() 
      File "/home/---/Code/RobotFlexTester/flex_usb_class.py", line 25, in STM32_connect
        connection = serial.Serial(p.device, timeout = .01)
      File "/home/---/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
        self.open()
      File "/home/janey/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
        raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/ttyACM2: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM2'
```

I can change COM ports and I receive the exact same error at a different ttyACM port. But I can connect to the same device on the same port if I try to run a different python script. The problem seems to somehow be locked to the initial test script but `ps -a` does not show it to still be running. The problem goes away without me doing anything after about 30 seconds - 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 30s to 1min delay are due to the internals of RS232 protocol. see the `closing_wait` option ( default 30 sec ) in `setserial` command ( http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/setserial.8.html ) when disconnecting USB cable and connection is killed the protocol waits for the time specified in the `closing_wait` option until it closes the port / session.  `session_lockout` forbids attaching a second process to an open port...